# Spring Boot Integration test throws error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000 MILLISECONDS"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

The issue happens on my project that uses Spring webflux via Spring boot 2.0.0.M3. Below is the dependencies of project,

```
dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
                'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config',
                'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-stream',
                'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth',
                'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit',
                'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive',
                'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive',
                'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration',
                "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp",
                "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb",
                'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry',
                'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux',
                "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools",
                'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda',
                'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9',
                'org.javamoney:moneta:1.0',
                'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1',
                "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.11",
                'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
        testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
                'io.projectreactor:reactor-test',
                'org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker:6.1.2',
                'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'

        integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
        integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
        integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
        integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
    }
```

I have an REST API, and the code is below:

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/internal/note")
    @Slf4j
    public class NoteController {

        @Autowired
        NoteRepository noteRepository;

        @GetMapping("/request/{id}")
        public Mono<Note> getNoteByRequestid(@PathVariable("id") String requestid) {
            logger.debug("Requesting note by request id '{}'.", requestid);
            return noteRepository.findByRequestid(requestid).doOnSuccess(note ->
                    logger.debug("Found note '{}'.", note))
                    .doOnSuccess(response -> logger.debug("Successfully found note by request id '{}'.", requestid));
        }
    }
```

The code works fine. When calling the API using Postman, it returns the correct result.

I have the Integration test code like below:

```
final String data = "{xxxxx}";//JSON Data
    final Note newNote = noteRepository.save(objectMapper.readValue(data, Note.class)).block(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
            final String requestid = "5982C7366FF1C55D20CF2B70";
            this.webClient.get().uri("/internal/note/request/{id}", requestid).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
```

But the test fails throwing error message like below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000 MILLISECONDS

        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:109)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.toResponseSpec(DefaultWebTestClient.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:269)
        at cn.demo.handler.NoteHandlerTest.testGetNoteByRequestidWithPriceField(NoteHandlerTest.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any advice on how to solve the issue?

Comment: i have the same problem and i fix it by overiding the time-out https://stackoverflow.com/a/49496309/4215474

Comment: I overid the timeout and it work for me check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49496309/4215474

Comment: Did you find a solution for your error? I am stuck with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in the Framework, but given the amount of stuff you've got on the classpath, you should try to create a minimal, sample project reproducing that and open an issue against Spring Framework (https://jira.spring.io).

Answer (score 0):

The request timeout defaults to 5 seconds. Do your tests take longer than that to run? Maybe while you're actively using your computer simultaneously for other tasks and processes?

If so, when you configure your `WebTestClient`, set the [`responseTimeout()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.Builder.html#responseTimeout-java.time.Duration-) to something higher, like so:

```java
@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    webTestClient =
        webTestClient
            .mutate()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30000))
            .build();
}
```