# Webflux Webclient - increase my Webclient time out (wait a bit more a flaky service)

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Small question regarding Spring Webflux Webclient, and how to increase the client side time out please.

Setup, I am the client, I need to consume a third party API over the web.

This third party API is known to be flaky. For a same request, same response, sometimes, it takes 1-2sec, sometimes more than 4-5secs (mostly 4-5secs )

But it is a good and important API, the payload response is very important.

Hence, I believe it is worth to "wait them longer".

May I ask how to do that please?

After investigation, this third party API do see some 499 response from their VIP.

I believe this means "I did not want to wait". But I do want to wait longer!

After looking at the Webclient API, I am having a hard time finding how to do this.

Currently, I am constructing my WebClient as such:

```
WebClient.create().mutate().defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().metrics(true, () -> new MicrometerChannelMetricsRecorder(SERVICE, HTTP)).wiretap(true).secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(getSslContextBuilder())))).build()
```

What is the current default time out?

How to increase it please via property or code?

Something like :

```
.setDefaultClientSideWaitTime() ?
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: there is a section on the spring reference documentation on how to do this. Please have a read through and update your question if there is still anything unclear.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per answer from Netty Team, it needs:

```
.responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))

.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10 * 1000)
```

For an example to wait 10 seconds

and

```
conn.addHandlerLast

.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10L))
```

Are not needed

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a `responseTimeout` as done for `WebTestClient` here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655749/4725964

Comment: this can be a comment to question