# WebFlux timeout every 60 second when there is no content

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a problem with sending data to the client by webflux. When there is no content in Flux for about 60 seconds, response is aborted by server. Is there any possibility to "wait" for response as long as client want to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might be helpful

```
.responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))

.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10 * 1000)
```

you can also refer this: [Webflux Webclient - increase my Webclient time out (wait a bi more a flaky service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66325962/webflux-webclient-increase-my-webclient-time-out-wait-a-bi-more-a-flaky-servi)

Comment: the problem is on the server side, because server abort connection, not client

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Kubernetes has default value of 60 seconds for every request, so every time (for webflux) when there is no content, then reuqest is aborted (for me with status 200)